# Delete Object by array with timestamp

Tags: timestamp, nsarray, nstimer

I wanted to know how we can delete items or objects from an array after a while, as if at the end of the countdown, the element of the array is canceled automatically

Comment: Give more details about what you have and what you have tried. What is the trigger for the deletion (time, user action, ...)?

Comment: I want to delete some object after for example one hour but i don't know how i can do it

Comment: Have you looked at `NSTimer`? Got a timestamp in your data?

Comment: I am seeing NSTimer but I don't but I can not figure out how to delete a countdown

Answer (score 0):

Your data model should include a timestamp with each object to be deleted. The timestamp could contain the time that the item should be deleted or the time at which it was created.

You should have an `NSTimer` instance that runs periodically (repeatedly), perhaps once per minute, and checks the data model to see if anything needs to be deleted.

When the timer fires, iterate over the objects in your data model, check the timestamp to see if the item needs to be deleted and delete as appropriate.

Comment: you give an example of practical code please?, because I try to put it into practice but continues to give me errors thanks

Comment: Update your question with the code you tried and then we'll correct it.